# Can I willingly fail a Virtue roll?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

In *Vampire The Masquerade*, can I decide to willingly fail a Virtue roll?

If I feel that, in the situation calling for the roll, my character wouldn't control themselves, can I just leave my dices down, look at the GM and tell him that I failed the roll?

Is there a rule allowing that action or is it something situational that I should discuss with my GM to see if he'll allow it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Sure.

Just as you can decide not to dodge, or otherwise choose not to avoid harm coming to you, you can choose to give into your Frenzy or decide as a character point that your Humanity decreases due to your acts. That's "choosing not to resist," though, rather than "failing a roll."